# Error Ajxa call in asp.net xhr.send( options.hasContent && options.data || null )

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-5.0

I tried to so hard to solve it but couldn't.

I got error

> xhr.send( options.hasContent && options.data || null )

while saving data this error shows in Jquery.js.

Code is working perfectly in debug mode in vs 2022. I can save data in debug mode. But when
I compile (Publish) this project. I hosted in IIS and every things working perfectly but not in this form When I try to post data then I got same error.

I tried to send header but not working..

> var token =
> $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val();
> headers: { RequestVerificationToken: token },

```
        var detailsList = new Array();
        var detailsObj = new Object();

        $("#tblDropItem tbody tr").each(function () {
            let row = $(this);
            let itemId = Number(row.find('.item_detl').attr('purItem_id'));
            detailsObj = {
                ItemId: itemId,
                ItemName: row.find(".item_detl").val(),
                Quantity: parseFloat(row.find(".quantity_detl").val()),
                UnitId: Number(row.find('.unit_detl').attr('unit_id')),
                Rate: parseFloat(row.find(".rate_detl").val()),
                Amount: parseFloat(row.find(".amount_detl").val()),
            }
            if (detailsObj.ItemName) {
               detailsList.push(detailsObj);
            }
        });

     var postData = {
            PurMode: $("#PurMode").val(),
            PurDate: $("#PurDate").val(),
            SupId: $("#SupId option:selected").val(),
            SubAmount: parseFloat($("#SubAmount").val()),
            Discount: parseFloat($("#DiscountPercent").val()),
            DiscountAmount: parseFloat($("#Discount").val()),
            TotalAmount: parseFloat($("#TotalAmount").val()),
            Remarks: $("#Remarks").val(),
            Taxable: parseFloat($("#Taxable").val()),
            VatAmount: parseFloat($("#VatAmount").val()),
            VATable: parseFloat($("#VATable option:selected").val())
            
            PurchaseDetailItemList: detailsList,
            __RequestVerificationToken: $("input[name=__RequestVerificationToken]").val(),
        }
        
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Purchase/SavePurchase",
            dataType: 'JSON',
            data: postData,
            async:false,
            success: function (result) {
                toastr.success('Data Saved Successfully');
                window.location = "@Url.Content("~/Purchase/Index")";
                
            },
            error: function (result) {
                toastr.error("Cann't Save Data.");
            }
        });


    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public JsonResult SavePurchase(PurchaseDTO model)
    {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
               return Json("error");
            }
      //code...
    }
```

Can you please suggest any mistake..

Comment: You are getting that error because of this `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` attribute. Two solutions you have , either remove `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]`  or pass token this way `$.ajaxSetup({beforeSend:function(xhr){xhr.setRequestHeader('Token', '@accessToken');}});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is correct, maybe you have hosted incorrectly in iis, make sure your post url is valid in console.